# Remove white margin on header and footer

Tags: css, wordpress

I have made my WordPress template page for a custom theme. Now I am failing to understand why am I having a white empty margin to my right hand side.
Here http://dev.onezimbabwe.com/test/

How can I solve this?

Comment: share your code in the site and not a link to your website ... it's even wors when the link is a dev one that will get dead for sure! so this questions will have no sense in the future

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

add overflow-x hidden to your class "always_vert_scroll" 
  this will solve your problem.

Comment: yes I am the downvoter because i discourage to answer to such question even if the answer is correct ... the OP included a dev link to his site and this link will be dead for sure so the answer/question will have no sense in the future ... by answering such question we encourage people to post them again and again

Answer (score -2):

find a theme's css or html code in WordPress directory and make the following changes

```
body { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: yes I am the downvoter because i discourage to answer to such question even if the answer is correct ... the OP included a dev link to his site and this link will be dead for sure so the answer/question will have no sense in the future ... by answering such question we encourage people to post them again and again

Comment: @TemaniAfif SO take advantages of some automatic scripts that clean up things. Also some moderators have privilege to clean up bad questions. If a question is not useful it should be deleted. But its meaningless to downvote answers `even if the answer is correct`

Comment: @masoudkeshavarz it's not meaningless to downvote... downvoting theses answer will discourage new people to answer them as they are simply looking for some reputation, so it's good to tell them that the purpose is not only to gain reputation but also to have a some good ressources in this site. And i know that these kind of question will be deleted but since they get answered before, people will still ask them because the logic is : " I will ask my bad question, i will get my answer, then i don't mind if it get removed" : So if no one answer we will avoid such questions.

Comment: @Temani Afif  If the answer was correct then you must have see my reputation here and then you can clearly see that I am new user here who is looking for reputation. If I already had a lot of reputation then you should have down voted me for doing so because  by that much experience I should not have answer it in first place.

Comment: `you can clearly see that I am new user here who is looking for reputation` : this is exactly why am downvoting the answer, because i know new users are simply looking for reputation and this doens't need to be the main purpose .. we need to provide good ressources for the website and not encourage bad question and simply looking for reputation. If you want reputation consider answering well asked question and you will get reputation and provide good ressources for the site which will also be good for you.

Comment: its not like that I was just answering for reputation. Yes that was motive but not only that. I am just trying to say that instead of down voting me you could have simply explain to me how this question is bad and why should not answer such questions. By that I can learn from senior person like you instead of getting demotivated. i.e. How to locate good questions? How to avoid bad questions?